# Unknown column with LEFT JOIN and regular JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

It's been awhile since I did any SQL and i'm currently trying to LEFT JOIN some tables to my old JOIN query, to be able to get certain data.

I'm however getting "Unknown column 'a.shop_id' i on clause" and I'm not sure why 'a.shop_id' is unknown.

```
SELECT
    e.campaign_desc,
    e.campaign_type_id,
    e.shop_id AS campaign_shop_id,
    a.*,
    b.*,
    a.id AS shop_item_id,
    c.cat_id AS category_id
FROM
    `shop_item` a, 
    `shop` b,
    `product` c
LEFT JOIN 
    `campaign_category` d ON 
            d.category_id = c.cat_id
LEFT JOIN 
    `campaign` e ON
            e.`id` = d.`campaign_id` 
        AND e.`shop_id` = a.`shop_id`
WHERE
    a.`product_id` = 23 AND
    b.`id` = a.`shop_id` AND
    b.`active_shop` = 1 AND
    a.`product_id`= c.`id` 
ORDER BY
    a.`item_price` DESC,
    a.`shop_id`
```

So I had to try something different so I had another query idea to test and that one works fine. But of course thats not what I'm after since i want multiple data columns.

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    a.shop_id,
    b.*,
    a.id AS shop_item_id,
    c.cat_id AS category_id,
    (SELECT t2.campaign_desc 
        FROM 
            campaign_category t1, campaign t2 
        WHERE 
            t1.category_id = c.cat_id AND
            t2.id = t1.campaign_id AND
            t2.shop_id = a.`shop_id`
    )AS Campaigndata
FROM
    `shop_item` a, 
    `shop` b,
    `product` c
WHERE
    a.`product_id` = 23 AND
    b.`id` = a.`shop_id` AND
    b.`active_shop` = 1 AND
    a.`product_id`= c.`id` 
ORDER BY
    a.`item_price` DESC,
    a.`shop_id`
```

What am I missing in the first query? Help would be much appreciated.

Best Regards

Comment: Mixing implicit and explicit joins is very bad..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

So, rephrase the query as:

```
SELECT . . . 
FROM shop_item si JOIN
     shop s
     ON s.id = si.shop_id JOIN
     product p
     ON si.product_id = p.id LEFT JOIN 
     campaign_category cc 
     ON cc.category_id = p.cat_id LEFT JOIN 
     campaign c
     ON c.id = cc.campaign_id 
        c.shop_id = si.shop_id
WHERE si.product_id = 23 AND
      s.active_shop = 1
. . .
```

Notice that I also changed the table aliases so they are abbreviations for the table names, rather than meaningless, random letters.

The problem with your query is that `,` affects the scoping of identifiers being used.  It really isn't important to understand this, because the more important point is to *always use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax*.

Comment: For now on I will always write proper explicit SQL :)